# Chrome doesn't shutdown correctly when running Selenium script

Tags: java, selenium

Each time when I am running test cases, it shows the same issue. I also cannot start test cases from the beginning as it shows logged in to that site.

[image: Chrome error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be that can help you :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver  driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I do not know if it will be helpful or not but it should handle that notification.

Please do let me know if it worked or not.